How do I pass custom array containers to np.where?
I'm trying to use np.ndarrays in my custom class as one of the attributes (myClass.data) and following this guide in the NumPy docs https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.dispatch.html for Writing custom array containers. I've managed to register array_function implementations for np.sum, np.mean, np.std however I cannot figure out how to do this for np.where, leading to RecursionErrors.
This is a mockup of my current approach, with the relevant class information. This is mostly from following the guide so the array, array_ufunc and array_function are taken from there with small changes to adapt it to my class.
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy.lib.mixins
from numbers import Number

HANDLED_FUNCTIONS = {}


def implements(np_function):
    def decorator(func):
        HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[np_function] = func
        return func
    return decorator


class myClass(numpy.lib.mixins.NDArrayOperatorsMixin):
    def __init__(self, name, data: ArrayLike, index: ArrayLike):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
        self.index = index

    def __array__(self, dtype=None, copy=None):
        if copy is False:
            raise ValueError(
                "`copy=False` isn't supported. A copy is always created."
            )
        return self.data

    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
        if method == '__call__':
            _index = None
            scalars = []
            for input in inputs:
                if isinstance(input, Number):
                    scalars.append(input)
                elif isinstance(input, self.__class__):
                    scalars.append(input.data)
                    if _index is not None:
                        if _index != input.index:
                            raise TypeError("inconsistent sizes")
                    else:
                        _index = input.index
                else:
                    return NotImplemented
            return self.__class__(self.name, ufunc(*scalars, **kwargs), _index)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
        if func not in HANDLED_FUNCTIONS:
            return NotImplemented
        if not all(issubclass(t, self.__class__) for t in types):
            return NotImplemented
        return HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[func](*args, **kwargs)


@implements(np.mean)
def mean(arr):
    return np.mean(arr.data)


@implements(np.sum)
def sum(arr):
    return np.sum(arr.data)


@implements(np.where)
def where(condition, x, y):
    if isinstance(x, myClass):
        x = x.data
    if isinstance(y, myClass):
        y = y.data
    return np.where(condition, x, y)

The error when trying to call this like np.where(myclassobj > 1, 0, 1) is:
File ~test.py:74, in where(condition, x, y)
     72 if isinstance(y, myClass):
     73     y = y.data
---> 74 return np.where(condition, x, y)

File ~test.py:53, in myClass.__array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
     51 if func not in HANDLED_FUNCTIONS:
     52     return NotImplemented
---> 53 if not all(issubclass(t, self.__class__) for t in types):
     54     return NotImplemented
     55 return HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[func](*args, **kwargs)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Does anyone have any experience implementing np.where for custom arrays? I've looked at dask and cupy to see their implementation but hard to figure it out.
Py3.10, numpy 1.26.4

fwiw, here's my implementation. I haven't totally understood your implementation yet but I'm wondering why you didn't have to do condition.data?

Your where doesn't check the class of the condition.  What is myclassobj > 1?

Thanks Roy, I looked at your implementation and was able to modify mine, I had to convert all the inputs to myclass and it works, I was initially trying to just use the underlying ndarrays and have np.where return a ndarray as well but actually works out better this way.

@hpaulj The condition evaluates using the ndarray in self.data so it just came out as a bool ndarray(in my code proper, I've defined the lt, gt etc methods to operate on the .data attribute), changed it now to use the class
